# Having some trouble exporting DataGridView Data to excel

Tags: vb.net, excel, datagridview, export-to-excel

I have `DataGridView1` with the following headers.

`VENCD`, `ITEMUPC`, `RTLNUM`, `RTLPRICE`, `PROMO1`, `FROM1`, `TO1`, `PROMO2`, `FROM2`, `TO2`, `PROMO3`, `FROM3`, `TO3`

Using `DatePicker1`, I am filtering `DataGridView1` to show only rows where `DatePicker1.Value.Date = FROM1 OR FROM2 OR FROM3`

```
DirectCast(DataGridView1.DataSource, DataTable).DefaultView.RowFilter = String.Format("[FROM1] = '{0:M/d/yyyy}' OR [FROM2] = '{0:M/d/yyyy}' OR [FROM3] = '{0:M/d/yyyy}'", DatePicker.Value.Date)
```

This is the part where I'm stuck.
I need to export the data to excel (xlsx or csv) using this psuedo code.

```
if DatePicker1.Value.Date = FROM1 then 
    If PROMO1.Contains("/") Then
        Dim words As String() = PROMO1.Split(New Char() {"/"c})
        'If promo1 contains / (ex: 4/5.00) then
        RTLNUM = word(0) 'RTLNUM = 4
        RTLPRICE = word(1) 'RTLPRICE = 5.00
        export = VENCD, ITEMUPC, RTLNUM, RTLPRICE, PROMO1, FROM1, TO1

elseif DatePicker1.Value.Date = FROM2 then 
    If PROMO2.Contains("/") Then
        Dim words As String() = PROMO2.Split(New Char() {"/"c})
        RTLNUM = word(0)
        RTLPRICE = word(1)
        export = VENCD, ITEMUPC, RTLNUM, RTLPRICE, PROMO2, FROM2, TO2

elseif DatePicker1.Value.Date = FROM3 then 
    If PROMO3.Contains("/") Then
        Dim words As String() = PROMO3.Split(New Char() {"/"c})
        RTLNUM = word(0)
        RTLPRICE = word(1)
        export = VENCD, ITEMUPC, RTLNUM, RTLPRICE, PROMO3, FROM3, TO3
```

In terms of working code, this is what I have so far, however,

1) this code takes way too long to complete, and

2) it doesnt fully loop through the `DataGridView1` (as in 211/236 being exported)

```
        For item = 0 To DataGridView1.Rows.Count - 1 Step 1

            Dim VENCD As String = DataGridView1.Rows(item).Cells(0).Value.ToString()
            Dim ITEMUPC As String = DataGridView1.Rows(item).Cells(1).Value.ToString()
            Dim RTLNUM As String = DataGridView1.Rows(item).Cells(2).Value.ToString()
            Dim RTLPRICE As String = DataGridView1.Rows(item).Cells(3).Value.ToString()
            Dim PROMO1 As String = DataGridView1.Rows(item).Cells(4).Value.ToString()
            Dim FROM1 As String = DataGridView1.Rows(item).Cells(5).Value.ToString()
            Dim TO1 As String = DataGridView1.Rows(item).Cells(6).Value.ToString()
            Dim PROMO2 As String = DataGridView1.Rows(item).Cells(7).Value.ToString()
            Dim FROM2 As String = DataGridView1.Rows(item).Cells(8).Value.ToString()
            Dim TO2 As String = DataGridView1.Rows(item).Cells(9).Value.ToString()
            Dim PROMO3 As String = DataGridView1.Rows(item).Cells(10).Value.ToString()
            Dim FROM3 As String = DataGridView1.Rows(item).Cells(11).Value.ToString()
            Dim TO3 As String = DataGridView1.Rows(item).Cells(12).Value.ToString()

            If FROM1 = DatePicker1.Value.Date.ToString Then
                If PROMO1.Contains("/") Then
                    Dim words As String() = PROMO1.Split(New Char() {"/"c})
                        outputstring = VENCD & "," & ITEMUPC & "," & words(0) & "," & words(1) & "," & FROM1 & "," & TO1 & ", 20"
                        outputFile.WriteLine(outputstring)
                Else
                    outputstring = VENCD & "," & ITEMUPC & "," & RTLNUM & "," & RTLPRICE & "," & FROM1 & "," & TO1 & ", 20"
                    outputFile.WriteLine(outputstring)
                End If

            ElseIf FROM2 = DatePicker1.Value.Date.ToString Then
                If PROMO2.Contains("/") Then
                    Dim words As String() = PROMO2.Split(New Char() {"/"c})
                        outputstring = VENCD & "," & ITEMUPC & "," & words(0) & "," & words(1) & "," & FROM2 & "," & TO2 & ", 20"
                        outputFile.WriteLine(outputstring)
                Else
                    outputstring = VENCD & "," & ITEMUPC & "," & RTLNUM & "," & RTLPRICE & "," & FROM2 & "," & TO2 & ", 20"
                    outputFile.WriteLine(outputstring)
                End If

            ElseIf FROM3 = DatePicker1.Value.Date.ToString Then
                If PROMO3.Contains("/") Then
                    Dim words As String() = PROMO3.Split(New Char() {"/"c})
                        outputstring = VENCD & "," & ITEMUPC & "," & words(0) & "," & words(1) & "," & FROM3 & "," & TO3 & ", 20"
                        outputFile.WriteLine(outputstring)
                Else
                    outputstring = VENCD & "," & ITEMUPC & "," & RTLNUM & "," & RTLPRICE & "," & FROM3 & "," & TO3 & ", 20"
                    outputFile.WriteLine(outputstring)
                End If
            End If
        Next
```

any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Do you get any errors? Have you tried debug.printing each row to ensure you're getting through them all? Do you need to get the Date portion of From1 / From2 / From3? Add a final Else and see if anything is falling in there i.e didn't meet the first 3 criteria.

Comment: im not getting any errors. when i click export, the file is created (sample has 236 in datagridview count) and 211 entries are written to the csv. entry 212 only saved 4 of the 7 cells (TO3 FROM3 and PROMO3 doesnt get saved). adding a 4th `else` to see if anything falls thought, but if the first 3 criteria arent met, then the datagridview count would be 0

Comment: adding a 4th else does nothing as theres nothing to export if the date doesnt match from1-3

Comment: Add a forth exporter before your first IF. If that file has all your rows, then at least you know you're parsing all the rows.

Comment: strange, Ive exported 1802 out of 1831 entries when exporting all in datagridview. guess i need to figure out why that is before i can move on. thank for your help

Comment: Possibly try a `  For Each dgvRow As DataGridViewRow In DataGridView1.Rows` in place of `For item =` and also show the RowCount before you start looping to be sure how many you're expecting.